# Java nested generic type mismatch

Tags: java, generics, java-6, nested-generics

In the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
    first(b);
    second(b);

    List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    third(a);
    fourth(a);  // doesnt work

}

private static <T> void first(List<T> a){
    System.out.println("List of T");
}

private static void second(List<?> a){
    System.out.println("List of anything ");
}

private static <T> void third(List<List<T>> a){
    System.out.println("List of a List of T ");
}

private static void fourth(List<List<?>> a){
    System.out.println("List of a List of anything ");
}
```

**Why does the call to second(b) work, but the call to fourth(a) doesn't** ?

I get the following error:

```
The method fourth(List<List<?>>) in the type `TestTest` is not applicable for the arguments (`List<List<String>>`)
```

Comment: You're facing **`Type Erasure mechanism`** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Sure, but why doesn't it work for List<List<String>> ?

Comment: Its not nested - its transitory.  big difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to be able to call `fourth` with a `List<List<String>>` argument, then you'll need to change your signature to this:

```
private static void fourth(List<? extends List<?>> a){
    System.out.println("List of a List of anything ");
}
```

The above will work because unlike `List<List<?>>`, `List<? extends List<?>>` is compatible with `List<List<String>>`. Think of it this way:

```
List<List<String>> original = null;
List<? extends List<?>> ok  = original; // This works
List<?> ok2                 = original; // So does this
List<List<?>> notOk         = original; // This doesn't

List<Integer> original      = null;
List<? extends Number> ok   = original; // This works
List<?> ok2                 = original; // So does this
List<Number> notOk          = original; // This doesn't
```

The reasoning is simple. If you had

```
private static void fourth(List<List<?>> a) {
    List<?> ohOh = Arrays.asList(new Object());
    a.add(ohOh);
}
```

And then if you *could* call that method as such:

```
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
fourth(a);
String fail = a.get(0).get(0); // ClassCastException here!
```

Comment: +1 liked the answer but more explanation is required why `? extends List<?>` works?

Comment: Spot-on answer Lukas! But I believe the last line should read `String fail = a.get(0).get(0)`.

Comment: Why is List<? extends List<?>> a super-type of List<List<String>>?

Comment: @user1799796: I'm not sure if I got the terms right. The types are certainly compatible, though. I have added an analogy, which isn't quite the same thing, but similar. It may feel more intuitive, when you have a `List<? extends Number>`, rather than a `List<? extends List<?>>`.

Comment: So basically if you have `class A<T>`, and a variable `A<?> anObj = ...` (or `A<? extends whatever>`), you can't invoke any methods on `anObj` that have arguments of type `T` in the declaration, right?

Comment: @Andy: Almost. You can always pass the `null` literal, as `null` is a valid value for `?`. Try `List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); list.add(null);`

Answer (score 5):

A `List<List<String>>` isn't a `List<List<?>>`.

You should be able to put any `List<?>` into a `List<List<?>>`, no matter what the `?`. A `List<List<String>>` will only accept a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

> This implies that the type is unknown and objects of any type can be added to `List<List<?>>`   that are `heterogeneous` and compiler cannot guarantee that all object in `List<List<?>>` are of same type. Hence it cannot be passed to new `ArrayList<List<String>>()` that takes a bounded type as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`List<List<String>>` is not same as `List<List<?>>`. Generics are invariant in nature. If you only do `List<?>` and pass `List<String>` then it will work because `List of Anything` can be represented by `Lists of String`.

But `List of List of anything` can not be represented by `List of List of String`.

[`@Lukas Elder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229979/java-nested-generic-type-mismatch/13230201#13230201) has already specified case that will work. Here is the second case that will work

```
private static void fourth(List<?> a){
    System.out.println("List of anything ");
}
```

Comment: So your saying there is no flexibility in Java generic type parameters?  When a type parameter is used within a generic the instantiated object expects exactly the type specified when the generic type parameter is used?

Comment: @kmb385 I must admit I have failed to interpret meaning of the comment.Flexibility in Generic types using `wild cards` , `bounded wind cards` or `bounded types`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<?>> == List {                 //That contains any unknown type lists
                        List<Integer>,
                        List<String>,
                        List<Object>
                      }
```

Where as

```
List<? extends List<?> == List {       //That contains same unknown type lists
                        List<Integer>,
                        List<Integer>,
                        List<Integer>
                      }
```

So here

```
 List<List<String>> == List {        //That contains same String lists
                        List<String>,
                        List<String>,
                        List<String>
                      }
```

Hence `List<? extends List<?>` is super type of `List<List<String>>` and assignable.

So valid value to call your `fourth` method is below.

```
    List<List<?>> a1 =  new ArrayList<List<?>>();
    a1.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    a1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    a1.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
```