# java method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, arguments, wildcard

I can't see why **size(test);** won't compile.  Can someone help me understand?

```
public class TestContainer<T extends Object> {
}
```

.

```
public class Main {
    public static int size(List<TestContainer<?>> list) {
        return list.size(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestContainer<Object>> test = new ArrayList<TestContainer<Object>>();
        size(test); // this does not compile
        test.size(); // of course this works fine
    }
}
```

Comment: compiler might have already told you.

Comment: Make it `size(List<? extends TestContainer<?>>)`.

Comment: or this size(List<?> list)

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Java nested generic type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229979/java-nested-generic-type-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

A method with as parameter a generic `List` can accept subclasses of the generic  type only if the `List` parameter declaration is parameterized with an upper bounded wildcard.

You don't declare any [upper bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)  (`<? extend T>`) for `List<TestContainer>` here :

```
public static int size(List<TestContainer<?>> list) {
    return list.size(); 
}
```

So you can only pass this exact type as parameter :

```
List<TestContainer<?>>
```

To achieve you want, you should so write :

```
public static int size(List<? extends TestContainer<?>> list) {
    return list.size(); 
}
```

Note that the upper bounded wildcard is designed to ensure the type safety of the passed List.
As a consequence, inside the method, you could not add anything in but `null`.
But for your use case (returning the size of the list), it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`List<TestContainer<Object>>` is not a `List<TestContainer<?>>`.

A `TestContainer<Integer>` is a `TestContainer<?>`. Therefore, you can add a `TC<Integer>` to a `List<TC<?>>`. Similarly, you can add a `TC<String>` to a `List<TC<?>>`.

However, a `TC<Integer>` is not a `TC<Object>` (because generics are invariant in Java), so you mustn't be allowed to add a `TC<Integer>` to a `List<TC<Object>>`. As such, a `List<TC<Object>>` isn't a `List<TC<?>>`.

If you make it so that you are unable to add anything (except literal null) to the List - by making the method parameter `List<? extends TC<?>>` (or `List<?>`, if you are really uninterested in the elements) - it is safe, and thus allowed.