# Incompatible return type while implementing interface method with generic wildcard return type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

The interface method definition is:

```
Optional<? extends ABC<String, String>> getContextInfo();
```

The following method implementation compiles successfully in the implementation:

```
Optional<XYZ<String, String>> getContextInfo(){
...
}
```

Here XYZ is a subclass of ABC.

However, if the interface method uses a Map within Optional as follows:

```
Optional<Map<String,? extends ABC<String, String>>> getContextWithMap();
```

the following method implementation fails on compilation with the error: *Attempting to use incompatible return type*

```
Optional<Map<String, XYZ<String, String>>> getContextWithMap(){
...
}
```

I use java 8 and haven't tested this on higher versions.
Why does compilation flag an incompatible return type error in this case? How can this be fixed?

Comment: "How can this be fixed?" Just change the method signature so that the two matches? I guess you can't do that (otherwise you wouldn't have asked)... What restrictions do you have? What can/can't you change?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229979/java-nested-generic-type-mismatch

Comment: I could fix it by adding the generic return type in my implementation but I don't like to have generics within my implementation. More interested in why it is unsafe, so that I can think about an alternate approach.

Comment: This boils down to asking why you can't assign a `Optional<Map<String, XYZ<String, String>>>` to a reference of type `Optional<Map<String,? extends ABC<String, String>>>`.

Comment: You still haven't said whether the link given by Savior answers your question. If it does, I'll close this as a dupe. If not, please explain why not.

Comment: I was going over the answers suggested above. Have closed this as a duplicate.